# socket() function tuple error in python "TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not int"

Tags: windows, python-3.x, sockets, networking, tuples

I tried to write a simple python code for send/receive message between server and client sides. When I define my computer as server, I get an error which is written below. Interestingly same code works in another pc.

Code for server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = '10.1.1.25' # static ip of the server pc
port = 5001
s.bind(5)
c, addr = s.accept()
print("Got connection from", addr)
while True:
   c.send("Server please type").encode()
   print("From Server :", c.recv(4096))

c.close()
```

I get this error:

```
   s.bind(5)
TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not int
```

I replaced **s.bind(5)** with **s.bind((host,port))** then I get this error:

```
   fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Code for Client:

```
import socket

s=socket.socket()
host="10.1.1.25"
port=5001
s.connect((host,port))

while True:
    try:
        print("from server:",s.recv(4096))
        s.send(input("write something").encode())
    except:
        break
s.close()
```

**NOTE:**    *I got these errors on windows 8.1,but it works on windows 10

 Client sample code works for each computer which I tried*

Thanks for your help. According to your recommendations I modified my code like this;

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = '10.1.1.25'
port = 5001
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
c,addr=s.accept()
print("Got connection from", addr)
while True:
    c.send(input("Server please type").encode())
    print("From Server :", c.recv(4096))
s.close()
```

Now It works on local IP (when I adjusted 127.0.0.1) and I can communicate by myself on one computer.Even though when I try to communicate with second computer, I dont receive any error but I dont get any output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server must *listen* before being able to accept incoming connection. So the correct sequence is:

```
s = socket.socket()
host = '10.1.1.25' # static ip of the server pc
port = 5001
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
end = False
while not end:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    # process c incoming connection from addr, optionaly set end = True
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the host to "127.0.0.1". 
You said that you want to connect on your own computer, the IP adress above is the IP adress of your computer(for all computers).